# Error when trying to assign a primary key value to a button?

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax-error, primary-key

[*the data from the table is printed from the database(phpmyadmin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I914Q.png)

The 'view more' button needs to have the primary key value for each row so that it shows different information for each event.

code:

```
<?php
try{
// Run a SQL query
  $sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM events";
  $rows=$db->query($sqlstr);
//loop through all the returned records and display them in a table
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo  "<tr><td >" . $row['eventCategory'] . "</td><td >" . $row['eventName'] . "</td><td >" . $row['time']. "</td><td >" . $row['description']  . "</td><td >" . "<a href='viewmore.php?event_id= $row['event_id']' id='viewbtn' name='viewbtn'>view more</a>"."</td></tr >" ;


  }

  echo "</table> <br>";
} catch (PDOException $ex){
  //this catches the exception when the query is thrown
  echo "Sorry, a database error occurred when querying the vehicle records. Please try again.<br> ";
  echo "Error details:". $ex->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When I run it, I get this error..

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

The error is on this line

```
echo  "<tr><td >" . $row['eventCategory'] . "</td><td >" . $row['eventName'] . "</td><td >" . $row['time']. "</td><td >" . $row['description']  . "</td><td >" . "<a href='viewmore.php?event_id= $row['event_id']' id='viewbtn' name='viewbtn'>view more</a>"."</td></tr >" ;
```

Comment: Remove the `'` around event_id, in the `<a>` portion of your echo.  No need to quote array indexes inside `"` portions.

Answer (score 0):

Add "" around $row['event_id'] works fine

```
<?php
try{
// Run a SQL query
  $sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM events";
  $rows=$db->query($sqlstr);
//loop through all the returned records and display them in a table
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo  "<tr><td >'".$row['eventCategory']."'</td><td >'".$row['eventName']."'</td><td >'".$row['time']."'</td><td >'".$row['description']."'</td><td >" . "<a href='viewmore.php?event_id= ".$row['event_id']."' id='viewbtn' name='viewbtn'>view more</a>"."</td></tr >" ;


  }

  echo "</table> <br>";
} catch (PDOException $ex){
  //this catches the exception when the query is thrown
  echo "Sorry, a database error occurred when querying the vehicle records. Please try again.<br> ";
  echo "Error details:". $ex->getMessage();
}

?>
```